# Infopath form not opening for internal users

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, infopath, share

Please assist me on this. We created an info path form on a custom list and deployed it on our public facing site. our issue is that it asks for credentials although anonymous users is enabled.

Thanks

Comment: can u give more info about what SP version you using ?

Comment: Hi Michal, we using SP 2013 Enterprise version.